# Jar merging for the jdbc connection checking using izpack

Tags: java, jdbc, izpack

I am trying to create the installer using IZPACK 4.3.5.
I have to make sure that my db connection is a success or not by using my CustomPanel.

For that I did the following.
I have added my sqljdbc4.jar using jar tag in install.xml

```
<jar src="resources/jars/sqljdbc4.jar"/>
```

I created myapp.jar and when I tried to run using java -jar myapp.jar
I got the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file d
igest for Manifest main attributes
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVeri
fier.java:240)
```

Can you please let me know is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the real problem here is the usage of signed MSSQL driver, I would suggest you to use e.g. net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds instead which is open sourced and does not verify signature.

Comment: Thank you Zdeněk Vaník.I will try that. I found a work around..once we create the myapp.jar we just have to open the jar with winrar or 7z and go the META-INF folder and replace the .RSA and .SF files in that.now if you try to run the same JAR.. it will work....